# Are terminology question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked https://health.stackexchange.com/q/146/43 and I see that I received one close vote saying the question is off-topic. Are terminology questions on-topic?

Answer (score 8):

Asking what the difference is seems like a biology question to me and not related to health and hence off topic. If the question related to something a doctor said or something a person read about a health issue, then I think it would be on topic. This, however, seems like a subtle and silly distinction.

Comment: Yes, this isn't really a question about the subject of "health" *per se.* Without that context, it's a basic anatomy question better asked on something like Biology SE. The question is largely off topic for this site.